# Special character on Http Request

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android platform and trying to establish a http request but My Url contains some special characters So it is throwing an Exception.How to Avoid this problem.I did same thing In i-phone Using 
      [mystring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(**Copy of**)[URL Contains Special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295737/url-contain-special-charectors/4311267#4311267)
You can encode like this,

```
public class URLUTF8Encoder
{   
 final static String[] hex = {
 "%00", "%01", "%02", "%03", "%04", "%05", "%06", "%07",
 "%08", "%09", "%0a", "%0b", "%0c", "%0d", "%0e", "%0f",
 "%10", "%11", "%12", "%13", "%14", "%15", "%16", "%17",
 "%18", "%19", "%1a", "%1b", "%1c", "%1d", "%1e", "%1f",
 "%20", "%21", "%22", "%23", "%24", "%25", "%26", "%27",
 "%28", "%29", "%2a", "%2b", "%2c", "%2d", "%2e", "%2f",
 "%30", "%31", "%32", "%33", "%34", "%35", "%36", "%37",
 "%38", "%39", "%3a", "%3b", "%3c", "%3d", "%3e", "%3f",
 "%40", "%41", "%42", "%43", "%44", "%45", "%46", "%47",
 "%48", "%49", "%4a", "%4b", "%4c", "%4d", "%4e", "%4f",
 "%50", "%51", "%52", "%53", "%54", "%55", "%56", "%57",
 "%58", "%59", "%5a", "%5b", "%5c", "%5d", "%5e", "%5f",
 "%60", "%61", "%62", "%63", "%64", "%65", "%66", "%67",
 "%68", "%69", "%6a", "%6b", "%6c", "%6d", "%6e", "%6f",
 "%70", "%71", "%72", "%73", "%74", "%75", "%76", "%77",
 "%78", "%79", "%7a", "%7b", "%7c", "%7d", "%7e", "%7f",
 "%80", "%81", "%82", "%83", "%84", "%85", "%86", "%87",
 "%88", "%89", "%8a", "%8b", "%8c", "%8d", "%8e", "%8f",
 "%90", "%91", "%92", "%93", "%94", "%95", "%96", "%97",
 "%98", "%99", "%9a", "%9b", "%9c", "%9d", "%9e", "%9f",
 "%a0", "%a1", "%a2", "%a3", "%a4", "%a5", "%a6", "%a7",
 "%a8", "%a9", "%aa", "%ab", "%ac", "%ad", "%ae", "%af",
 "%b0", "%b1", "%b2", "%b3", "%b4", "%b5", "%b6", "%b7",
 "%b8", "%b9", "%ba", "%bb", "%bc", "%bd", "%be", "%bf",
 "%c0", "%c1", "%c2", "%c3", "%c4", "%c5", "%c6", "%c7",
 "%c8", "%c9", "%ca", "%cb", "%cc", "%cd", "%ce", "%cf",
 "%d0", "%d1", "%d2", "%d3", "%d4", "%d5", "%d6", "%d7",
 "%d8", "%d9", "%da", "%db", "%dc", "%dd", "%de", "%df",
 "%e0", "%e1", "%e2", "%e3", "%e4", "%e5", "%e6", "%e7",
 "%e8", "%e9", "%ea", "%eb", "%ec", "%ed", "%ee", "%ef",
 "%f0", "%f1", "%f2", "%f3", "%f4", "%f5", "%f6", "%f7",
  "%f8", "%f9", "%fa", "%fb", "%fc", "%fd", "%fe", "%ff"
 };  
    public static String encode(String s)
    {
      StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
      int len = s.length();
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      int ch = s.charAt(i);
      if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z') {     // 'A'..'Z'
       sbuf.append((char)ch);
      } else if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') {  // 'a'..'z'
       sbuf.append((char)ch);
      } else if ('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') {  // '0'..'9'
       sbuf.append((char)ch);
      } else if (ch == ' ') {           // space
       sbuf.append('+');
    } else if (ch == '-' || ch == '_'     // unreserved
       || ch == '.' || ch == '!'
       || ch == '~' || ch == '*'
       || ch == '\'' || ch == '('
       || ch == ')') {
      sbuf.append((char)ch);
    } else if (ch <= 0x007f) {        // other ASCII
      sbuf.append(hex[ch]);
    } else if (ch <= 0x07FF) {        // non-ASCII <= 0x7FF
      sbuf.append(hex[0xc0 | (ch >> 6)]);
      sbuf.append(hex[0x80 | (ch & 0x3F)]);
     } else {                  // 0x7FF < ch <= 0xFFFF
       sbuf.append(hex[0xe0 | (ch >> 12)]);
       sbuf.append(hex[0x80 | ((ch >> 6) & 0x3F)]);
       sbuf.append(hex[0x80 | (ch & 0x3F)]);
    }
   }
    return sbuf.toString();
       }
     }
```

referenced By

Comment: Referenced by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295737/url-contain-special-charectors/4311267#4311267

Answer (score 7):

Use the [URLEncoder class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html).

Example:

```
String argument = "Nårska täcken";
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(argument, "utf-8");
// encoded contains "N%C3%A5rska+t%C3%A4cken"
```

Just be careful you don't encode a whole URL query string in one go, since that ends up encoding the `?` and `=` as well.

```
String query = "?myQuery=Nårska+Täcken";
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(query "utf-8");
// XXX BAD! encoded contains "%3FmyQuery%3DN%C3%A5rska%2Bt%C3%A4cken"
```

Comment: Also note there seems to be a bug in android 2.2 that makes this not work. I don't want to look up the source right now, but I never found a solution and ended up just manually replacing the characters I needed to with their escaped values.

Comment: I agree with @Falmarri Comments