# Url contain special charectors

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to establish a https connection but my URL contains some special characters, so creating the connection is throwing an Exception.  How do I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can encode like this,

```
public class URLUTF8Encoder
{
 final static String[] hex = {
"%00", "%01", "%02", "%03", "%04", "%05", "%06", "%07",
"%08", "%09", "%0a", "%0b", "%0c", "%0d", "%0e", "%0f",
"%10", "%11", "%12", "%13", "%14", "%15", "%16", "%17",
"%18", "%19", "%1a", "%1b", "%1c", "%1d", "%1e", "%1f",
"%20", "%21", "%22", "%23", "%24", "%25", "%26", "%27",
"%28", "%29", "%2a", "%2b", "%2c", "%2d", "%2e", "%2f",
"%30", "%31", "%32", "%33", "%34", "%35", "%36", "%37",
"%38", "%39", "%3a", "%3b", "%3c", "%3d", "%3e", "%3f",
"%40", "%41", "%42", "%43", "%44", "%45", "%46", "%47",
"%48", "%49", "%4a", "%4b", "%4c", "%4d", "%4e", "%4f",
"%50", "%51", "%52", "%53", "%54", "%55", "%56", "%57",
"%58", "%59", "%5a", "%5b", "%5c", "%5d", "%5e", "%5f",
"%60", "%61", "%62", "%63", "%64", "%65", "%66", "%67",
"%68", "%69", "%6a", "%6b", "%6c", "%6d", "%6e", "%6f",
"%70", "%71", "%72", "%73", "%74", "%75", "%76", "%77",
"%78", "%79", "%7a", "%7b", "%7c", "%7d", "%7e", "%7f",
"%80", "%81", "%82", "%83", "%84", "%85", "%86", "%87",
"%88", "%89", "%8a", "%8b", "%8c", "%8d", "%8e", "%8f",
"%90", "%91", "%92", "%93", "%94", "%95", "%96", "%97",
"%98", "%99", "%9a", "%9b", "%9c", "%9d", "%9e", "%9f",
"%a0", "%a1", "%a2", "%a3", "%a4", "%a5", "%a6", "%a7",
"%a8", "%a9", "%aa", "%ab", "%ac", "%ad", "%ae", "%af",
"%b0", "%b1", "%b2", "%b3", "%b4", "%b5", "%b6", "%b7",
"%b8", "%b9", "%ba", "%bb", "%bc", "%bd", "%be", "%bf",
"%c0", "%c1", "%c2", "%c3", "%c4", "%c5", "%c6", "%c7",
"%c8", "%c9", "%ca", "%cb", "%cc", "%cd", "%ce", "%cf",
"%d0", "%d1", "%d2", "%d3", "%d4", "%d5", "%d6", "%d7",
"%d8", "%d9", "%da", "%db", "%dc", "%dd", "%de", "%df",
"%e0", "%e1", "%e2", "%e3", "%e4", "%e5", "%e6", "%e7",
"%e8", "%e9", "%ea", "%eb", "%ec", "%ed", "%ee", "%ef",
"%f0", "%f1", "%f2", "%f3", "%f4", "%f5", "%f6", "%f7",
"%f8", "%f9", "%fa", "%fb", "%fc", "%fd", "%fe", "%ff"
};
 public static String encode(String s)
 {
 StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
 int len = s.length();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  int ch = s.charAt(i);
  if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z') {     // 'A'..'Z'
    sbuf.append((char)ch);
  } else if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') {  // 'a'..'z'
       sbuf.append((char)ch);
  } else if ('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') {  // '0'..'9'
       sbuf.append((char)ch);
  } else if (ch == ' ') {           // space
       sbuf.append('+');
  } else if (ch == '-' || ch == '_'     // unreserved
      || ch == '.' || ch == '!'
      || ch == '~' || ch == '*'
      || ch == '\'' || ch == '('
      || ch == ')') {
    sbuf.append((char)ch);
  } else if (ch <= 0x007f) {        // other ASCII
       sbuf.append(hex[ch]);
  } else if (ch <= 0x07FF) {        // non-ASCII <= 0x7FF
       sbuf.append(hex[0xc0 | (ch >> 6)]);
       sbuf.append(hex[0x80 | (ch & 0x3F)]);
  } else {                  // 0x7FF < ch <= 0xFFFF
       sbuf.append(hex[0xe0 | (ch >> 12)]);
       sbuf.append(hex[0x80 | ((ch >> 6) & 0x3F)]);
       sbuf.append(hex[0x80 | (ch & 0x3F)]);
  }
}
return sbuf.toString();
}
```

}
referenced By
[HTTP://WWW.W3.ORG/INTERNATIONAL/URLUTF8ENCODER.JAVA](http://www.w3.org/international/URLUTF8Encoder.java)

Answer (score 2):

There are [several solutions](http://www.programmershere.com/questions-answers/217054-blackberry-url-encoder.html) for this. Pick the one you like most.