# Android(java) equilavent for NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:?

Tags: android, url, encoding, urlencode

I'm looking for the equivalent of the `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` method in Java (for Android).

I tried `URLEncoder.encode()` but it doesn't do the same.

I don't expect "/" or ":" to be "percent escaped" but "œ" (for example) should be.

Any ideas?

Edit:

I just don't want http:// to become http%3a%2f%2f

Comment: are you using UFT-8 for encoding a as  `URLEncoder.encode("your string", "utf-8")` if yes then see this post me be helpful for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290073/special-character-on-http-request

Comment: what is that even supposed to do ?

Comment: it's encoding special characters (e.g. œ becomes %5C%93) but NOT ":", "/", "_", "-" (perhaps more) because those are common characters in an url

Comment: @jafar true but urlencoder does percent-encoding, that is, the result can be safely passed as querystring parameter or POST data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you want to leave `:` and `/` untouched, I think you need to do it yourself, because that's not valid percent-encoding and therefore there is little chance for a solution already existing in java. I also checked the documentation for `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` and it doesn't behave like that either.

Comparing documentation, `URLEncoder.encode(string, encoding)` is exactly the same as the NS method, so your requirement is indeed weird. Here's the custom code anyway:

```
public static String stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding( String input, String charset ) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] bytes = input.getBytes(charset);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length);
    for( int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i ) {
        int cp = bytes[i] < 0 ? bytes[i] + 256 : bytes[i];
        if( cp <= 0x20 || cp >= 0x7F || (
            cp == 0x22 || cp == 0x25 || cp == 0x3C ||
            cp == 0x3E || cp == 0x20 || cp == 0x5B ||
            cp == 0x5C || cp == 0x5D || cp == 0x5E ||
            cp == 0x60 || cp == 0x7b || cp == 0x7c ||
            cp == 0x7d
            )) {
            sb.append( String.format( "%%%02X", cp ) );
        }
        else {
            sb.append( (char)cp );
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static String stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding( String input ) {
    try {
        return stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(input, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Java platforms are required to support UTF-8");
        // will never happen
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(
        stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/œäsd")
    );
    //http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%93%C3%A4sd

}
```

Comment: like you say it's weird because I'm using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding in an iOS app and http:// is not turned into http%3a%2f%2f

Comment: @jafar ok, the new custom code should work like that, check it out.

Comment: @Esailija- its working for me...I wanted the same like this..
Thanks :)